# How to define a global function dependent on a local pattern?

Tags: function-construction, scoping

When `g` is in the local scope defined by `Block`, the following fails:

```
Block[{g, x},
  g[x] = StringExpression[x : LetterCharacter];
  SetAttributes[f, Listable];
  f = Function[{str}, StringMatchQ[str, g[x]], Listable];
 ]
```

eg. `f[{"v", "e", "7", "2", "i"}]` produces the message `StringExpression::invld` with text "*Element g[x] is not a valid string or pattern element in g[x]*" and returns

> ```
> {StringMatchQ["v", g[x]], StringMatchQ["e", g[x]], 
>     StringMatchQ["7", g[x]], StringMatchQ["2", g[x]], 
>      StringMatchQ["i", g[x]]}
> ```

but instead when `g` is in the global scope ie when `g` is removed from the list of variables that are local to the `Block`, `f` works as expected.

On the previous example, evaluating `f[{"v", "e", "7", "2", "i"}]` returns `{True, True, False, False, True}`.

(Why is this happening and) would it be possible to make `f` work when `g` is local to the `Block`?

Comment: `Function` is `HoldAll` and once `Block` is done there is no reference to `g` which is inside `f`. You need to inject it with `With` or `Function[...] /. DownValues[g]`

Comment: @Kuba thanks! `With` doesn't work with `g[x]` but `/. DownValues[g]` does the trick; a quick follow-up: when I define `f` as in `SetAttributes[f, Listable]; f[str_] := StringMatchQ[str, g[x]]`, the problem persists for the same reasons?

Comment: Yes, because `SetDelayed` holds right hand side too.